# Can any one suggest some sublime plugin for converting huge list into comma separated?

Tags: sublimetext2

I am working on salesforce platform and to update it through data loader I need to provide input in csv format . I know I can do find and replace stuff. Just wondering in case any sublime plugin is there to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got to look into list2csv sublime plugin. Here is the link, 
https://github.com/avinash8526/List2CSV-Sublime-Plugin. Also you can download through package control.

Comment: Thanks dude worked like charm, and thanks to stackoverflow for replying so fast.